# Is it possible to use a windows environment path to configure the torrc file?

Tags: windows

is it possible to set an environment path in windows environment like this:

%tor% = "C:\users\user\blah blah\tor"

and then configure the torrc file to use this path for Data Directories?
Like this:

DataDirectory %tor%\Data Directories\Data1\Tor

GeoIPFile %tor%\Data Directories\Data1\Tor\geoip

GeoIPv6File %tor%\Data Directories\Data1\Tor\geoip6

Comment: Currently, it just reads the %tor% environment variable as part of the string. Not entirely sure if this is possible, figured I'd ask anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently. Neither the Tor Windows nor Linux version make any calls for environment variables like that.

Unrelated to Tor, developers/admins will sometimes hack around situations similar to this by building flat files off of the environment variables before an application executes. I've only seen these as shims/wrappers and not a long term solution though.